# ¿Cuando usar una función flecha(arrow function) en vez de una función común?

Tags: javascript

¿Cuándo usar una función flecha en JavaScript?

```
() => { console.log('test'); }

function() { console.log('test'); }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Esta [nueva sintaxis para funciones introducida en ES6](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2015/12/novedades-de-es6/) es funcionalmente equivalente a las funciones normales en la mayoría de las situaciones, sin embargo es importante notar las siguientes diferencias:

- Valor de `this`, las funciones normales capturan el valor de `this` como el objeto global (o `undefined` en [modo estricto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)):

  ```
  function Persona() {            
      this.edad = 0;

      setInterval(function crecer() {    
          this.edad++; // error lógico, no se refieren a la misma variable
      }, 1000);
  }
  ```

  Mientras que las funciones flecha capturan ese valor del [scope](http://www.enrique7mc.com/2015/12/concepto-de-scope-en-javascript/) externo inmediato:

  ```
  function Persona(){
      this.edad = 0;

      setInterval(() => {
          this.edad++; // correcto, this se refiere a una instancia de Persona
      }, 1000);
  }
  ```
- Argumentos, las funciones normales tienen acceso a una variable especial llamada `arguments` que es similar a un arreglo y contiene referencias a los argumentos que se pasan a una función:

  ```
  function foo(arg1, arg2) {
      console.log(arguments[0]);
  }

  foo("hola", "mundo"); // imprime "hola"
  ```

  En las funciones flecha, `arguments` se refiere a una variable en el *scope* exterior, si ésta variable no existe su valor es `undefined`:

  ```
  var arguments = 42;
  var arr = () => arguments;

  arr(); // 42
  ```

  A pesar de esto se puede implementar una funcionalidad similar con los [parámetros rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

  ```
  var foo = (...args) => {console.log(args[0])};
  foo("hola", "mundo"); // Imprime "hola"
  ```
- Si una función de flecha simplemente devuelve una sola línea de código, puede omitir los corchetes de la declaración y la palabra clave return. Esto le dice a la función de flecha que devuelva la declaración.

  ```
  const double = (num) => num * 2;
  ```
- Keyword `yield`, esta palabra reservada fue introducida también en ES6 y es utilizada en las [funciones generadoras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), sin embargo no puede ser utilizada en las funciones flecha.

Las funciones flecha proporcionan una sintaxis más elegante y compacta al ser usadas como *callbacks*, por lo que pueden ser usadas *casi* en las mismas situaciones que las funciones normales, y probablemente serán preferidas en futuras versiones de EcmaScript, solo hay que tomar en cuenta las diferencias anteriores para no cometer errores.

Answer (score 12):

Las funciones flecha o Arrow Functions no son solo una azúcar sintáctica para hacer mas fácil/elegante la declaración de función ordinaria. Hay considerables diferencias entre ambas que pueden hacer que un programa no funcione como se espera y no son intercambiables para muchos casos.

Por esto supongo que la pregunta completa es ¿cuando usarlas y cuando no?

### ¿Cuando usar Arrow Functions?

#### Sintaxis reducida de funciones puras.

En el siguiente bloque, son intercambiables por que son funciones puras (que su resultado no depende de una variable externa). En cuando performance, son [prácticamente iguales](http://jsperf.com/funciones-flecha/2).

```
// declaracion de funcion 
var nombres = personas.map(function(p){ return p.nombre });
// funcion flecha, este es un buen caso de uso
var nombres = personas.map(p => p.nombre);
```

#### Cuando quires que la función flecha se ejecute en el mismo *lexical scope* que la función contenedora:

Las funciones flecha se evalúan como parte del lexical scope que las contiene, por esto `this` y `arguments` no son instancias propias de la función flecha sino que son las instancias de la función contenedora. Este tipo de funciones no son intercambiables, deberás reescribir partes del cuerpo de la función si quieres cambiar de una sintaxis a la otra.

Considera este otro bloque:

```
// ECMAScript 5, usando una declaración de función.
function contadorDeSegundos() {
  var that = this;
  this.contar = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    that.contar++;
  }, 1000);
}

///  ECMAScript 2015, con arrow functions
function contadorDeSegundos() {
  this.contar = 0;                      
  setInterval(() => { this.contar++ }, 1000); 
}
```

Como ves aquí otra vez el código es mas compacto, pero el comportamiento de `this` es muy diferente.

## ¿Cuando *NO* usar Arrow Functions?

#### Cuando necesites argumentos dinámicos:

Como ya se estableció, la funciones flecha no exponen el objeto `arguments`, por lo tanto si necesitas acceso al mismo no puedes utilizarlas. Ten en cuenta que si la función flecha la declaras dentro de otra función, estarías accediendo al `arguments` de la función contenedora (si hubiese una). Por eso se dice las funciones flecha utilizan lexical arguments. Es decir, que ven el objeto `arguments` que esta en el lexical scope.

A nivel global:

```
var f = () => { console.log(arguments.length) }
f();
// produce: Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined(…)
var f2 = function() { console.log(arguments.length) }
f2();
// produce: 0
```

#### En funciones generador:

La palabra clave `yield` no esta permitida en funciones flecha. Estas funciones no pueden ser funciones generador (sin embargo pueden contener funciones generador).

Comment: Otro caso donde no se deben usar es al añadir métodos a un objeto o su prototipo: `obj.metodo=()=>{ this. ...}` fallará porque `this` nunca será el objeto esperado