# ¿Es posible cambiar el nombre de una propiedad en un Json o arreglo de Json?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Necesito cambiar el nombre a una propiedad Json proveniente de un arreglo

```
[
{
 nombre : 'Luis',
 apellido : 'Gonzales'
},
{
 nombre : 'Maria',
 apellido : 'Perez'
},
{
 nombre : 'Ignacia',
 apellido : 'Valdebenito'
}
]
```

y necesito modificarla de la siguiente manera

```
[
{
 nombreUsuario : 'Luis',
 apellidoUsuario : 'Gonzales'
},
{
 nombreUsuario : 'Maria',
 apellidoUsuario : 'Perez'
},
{
 nombreUsuario : 'Ignacia',
 apellidoUsuario : 'Valdebenito'
}
]
```

¿Es posible hacerlo mediante una función y no hacerlo mediante un bucle `for` que recorra el arreglo para ingresarlo en otro?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hay 2 partes en esta pregunta, una es como renombrar la propiedad y lo otra es como hacerlo para un arreglo.

Algunos métodos diferentes que puedes usar...

Las versiones actuales de Node.js (y los navegadores modernos) implementan [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) que te permite procesar un arreglo y obtener un resultado transformado. Este enfoque crea un nuevo objeto con las nuevas propiedades, es para una estructura -simple- como la utilizaste. De pocos campos.

```js
var arreglo = [{
  nombre: 'Luis',
  apellido: 'Gonzales'
}, {
  nombre: 'Maria',
  apellido: 'Perez'
}, {
  nombre: 'Ignacia',
  apellido: 'Valdebenito'
}];

// para cada elemento, se crea un nuevo objeto con las nuevas propiedades.
var arreglado = arreglo.map( item => { 
  return { nombreUsuario: item.nombre , apellidoUsuario : item.apellido }; 
});

console.log(arreglado);
```

Cuidado! Esta sintaxis no funcionara en versiones viejas de node 3.x, ni en navegadores viejos. Si necesitas hacerlo para node 3.x o navegadores viejos es muy parecido, debes cambiar la [función flecha](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4681/qu%C3%A9-es-en-javascript) por una declaración normal y utilizar [lodash.js](https://lodash.com/) o similar para tener la función [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map).

### Uso del operador [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete)

Si quieres renombrar una sola propiedad (o unas pocas), puedes hacer algo así, aprovechando el operador delete.

```js
var arreglo = [{
  nombre: 'Luis',
  apellido: 'Gonzales'
}, {
  nombre: 'Maria',
  apellido: 'Perez'
}, {
  nombre: 'Ignacia',
  apellido: 'Valdebenito'
}];

// para cada elemento... 
var arreglado = arreglo.map( item => { 
  // lo guardas temporalmente
  var temporal = item.nombre;
  // eliminas el valor que ya no quieres
  delete item.nombre;
  // creas el valor nuevo.
  item.nombreNuevo = temporal;
  return item; 
});

console.log(arreglado);
```

Claro que puedes hacerlo con un for, ya sea creando un obj o usando delete, pero map es mas *idiomatico*.

Por ultimo para la vieja escuela, en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key) del sitio en inglés, se propone un método para renombrar las propiedades.

```
Object.prototype.renameProperty = function (oldName, newName) {
  // no hacer nada si los nombre son iguales
  if (oldName == newName) {
    return this;
  }
  // Verificar si ya existe la propiedad con el nombre nuevo y evitar errores.
  if (this.hasOwnProperty(oldName)) {
    this[newName] = this[oldName];
    delete this[oldName];
  }
  return this;
};

// lo usas así... también podrías usar map, o un for común..
// eso dependerá de la compatibilidad que necesites y lo
// "modernizado" que quieras que sea tu código.
for (var item of arreglo) {
  item.renameProperty('nombre', 'nombreUsuario');
  item.renameProperty('nombre', 'apellidoUsuario');
}
```

Comment: que bien ! pero funciona en nodejs como ejecución desde servidor y no cliente? , gracias lo probaré !

Comment: @LuisAlbertoAguileraClarke depende de la version, en una version un poco vieja no va funcionar, pero si, esto es valido para node.

Comment: Crítica a la última sugerencia: Modificar prototipos de objetos estándares (y en particular de `Object`) es una **malísima** idea.

Comment: @rnd tomando el mismo ejemplo, si solo quiero renombrar el nombre y el apellido dejarlo intacto se puede o tendría que sobrescribir todas las demás propiedades?, esto usando map()

Comment: @JuankGlezz hay varias formas expuestas en la respuesta, para lo que dices, me parece mejor usar la opcion 2, del operador delete, ojo pues esta tiene el efecto colateral que modifica el objeto original.