# ¿Como reagrupar 2 JSON por una posicion determinada? Coloco 2 ejemplos para demostrar lo que deseo

Tags: jquery, html, sql, json

Tengo 2 ejemplos de los `select` que deseo generar uno bueno y uno malo. Allí veran.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var result_malo = [
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Bocina"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre": "Bocina Der"
       }
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Bocina"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "nombre": "Bocina Central"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Jeringa"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "nombre": "Jeringa Inf"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Jeringa"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre": "Jeringa Sup"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Mecanica"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "nombre": "Motor Principal"
        }
      ]
    ]
  ];
  $.each(result_malo, function(key, value) {
    $("#crear_subpartes_malo")
      .append('<optgroup label="' + value[0].nombre + '">');
    $("#crear_subpartes_malo")
      .append('<option value="' + value[1][0].id + '">' + value[1][0].nombre + '</option>');
    $("#crear_subpartes_malo").append('</optgroup>');
  });
  var result_bueno = [
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Bocina"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "nombre": "Bocina Der"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "nombre": "Bocina Central"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "nombre": "Jeringa"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "nombre": "Jeringa Inf"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "nombre": "Jeringa Sup"
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Mecanica"
      },
      [
        {
          "id": 7,
          "nombre": "Motor Principal"
        }
      ]
    ]
  ];
  $.each(result_bueno, function(key, value) {
    $("#crear_subpartes_bueno")
      .append('<optgroup label="' + value[0].nombre + '">');
    for (i = 0; i < value[1].length; i++) {
      $("#crear_subpartes_bueno")
        .append('<option value="' + value[1][i].id + '">' + value[1][i].nombre + '</option>');
    }
    $("#crear_subpartes_bueno").append('</optgroup>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="crear_subpartes_malo">Este es el select cargado con el JSON que obtengo</label>
 <br/>
 <select multiple id="crear_subpartes_malo" name="crear_subpartes_malo" style="width: 150px;height: 200px;"></select>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <label for="crear_subpartes_malo">Este es el select cargado con un JSON creado por mi</label>
 <br/>
 <select multiple id="crear_subpartes_bueno" name="crear_subpartes_bueno" style="width: 150px;height: 200px;"></select>
```

**Actualizacion 1:**

JSON: "result_bueno" este es como yo deseo que se ordene mi JSON
JSON: "result_malo" pero este es el que obtengo de la DB

Quisiera ordenarlo con `javascript` o `jQuery`, desde la DB no por que no hay manera o al menos yo no encuentro la manera.

**Actualización 2:**

Tengo 4 tablas para la consulta:

> equipos: id, nombre

> partes: id, nombre

> subpartes: id, nombre, id_subpartes

> equipos_subpartes: id, id_equipos, id_subpartes

Esta ultima es una puente, ¿Por que no relaciono `equipos` a `partes`? Pues porque hay nombres de `subpartes` que se repiten en unos `equipos` y es la única manera que se me ocurrió para evitar repetición de `nombres` en la tabla de `subpartes`. No se si lo estoy haciendo bien o si estoy equivocado son bienvenidas las sugerencias. PD: es la primera vez que trabajo una puente de esa manera.

La consulta la realizo con `laravel` de la siguiente manera:

```html
public function getSubpartes(Request $req, $id){
    if($req->ajax()){
        $result = 'select "subpartes"."id", "subpartes"."nombre" from "equipos_subpartes" inner join "subpartes" on "subpartes"."id" = "equipos_subpartes"."id_subpartes" where "equipos_subpartes"."id_equipos" = '.$id;
        $arrayFinal = array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
            $arrayPartes = array();
            $resultPartes = 'select "partes"."id", "partes"."nombre" from "subpartes" inner join "partes" on "partes"."id" = "subpartes"."id_partes" where "subpartes"."id" = '.current($result[$i]);
            for($j=0;$j<count($resultPartes);$j++){
                array_push($arrayFinal, array($resultPartes[$j] , $result[$i]));
            }
        }
        Debugbar::info($arrayFinal);
        return $arrayFinal;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más explícito? Personalmente no entiendo qué quieres hacer con exactitud.

Comment: @Guz se me hizo algo complicado explicarme, intentare ser mas explicito. Modificare la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes el JSON, por SQL u otro medio? ¿Puedes mostrar el código por el que obtienes el JSON? Creo que el problema no se trata de manipular un JSON para desechar lo que no quieres, sino de generar un JSON que muestre exactamente aquello que necesitas. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano por como tengo las tablas en la db es la unica manera que encontre de traer el registro, por eso intento ordenarlas en javascript, claro si es que existe la posibilidad.

Comment: @Guz ya especifique la pregunta

Comment: @PabloContreras  Precisamente... uno ordena las tablas de acuerdo a sus necesidades y si las mismas están bien concebidas no es necesario tener que "manipular" los resultados (en este caso el JSON) para desechar información innecesaria. En un buen diseño debes mostrar en cada consulta exactamente lo que necesitas, sin datos repetidos que luego haya que desechar. SQL te da muchísimas posibilidades de juntar tus tablas, de agruparlas, etc de forma que puedas obtener el resultado deseado. Si no muestras código es más difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Coloca tu consulta SQL, como dice @A.Cedano esto es conveniente hacero en la API que en el cliente.

Comment: @Guz ok un momento

Comment: @PabloContreras Quizá pueda servirte esta respuesta http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5187/6635

Comment: @Guz ya modifique la pregunta

Comment: @A.Cedano ya modifique la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trato de definir lo que quieres hacer: un listado de partes (Bocinas, Jeringas, etc) y debajo de cada una sus subpartes respectivas.

Para una próxima consulta, creo que sería bueno tratar de formular con palabras lo que quieres hacer en general, no sólo el resultado que quieres obtener... y mostrar parte de tu código.

De todos modos, me queda la duda sobre la tabla equipos, ya que no aparece nada sobre equipos en tu JSON no tengo idea de su función o utilidad.

Lo que muestras en tu JSON se podría obtener fácilmente con el diseño siguiente:

**a. Creación de tablas e inserción de valores**

Ojo: Por cuestiones de claridad y buena práctica de programación, acostúmbrate a dar a cada cosa nombres que cuando los veas sepas a qué te refieres. Si usas varias tablas y en cada una usas una columna llamada "nombre" para almacenar los nombres de las partes, subpartes, etc tendrás luego varias columnas llamadas "nombre". Aparte de que te podrías confundir con facilidad al crear tus SQL, cuando tengas que usar tres o más tablas en una consulta y te encuentres con varias columnas con el mismo nombre, vaya lío. Por eso verás que en las diferentes tablas cada columna se llama nombre_[algo que identifique] .

```
CREATE TABLE Partes
    (`id_parte` int, `nombre_parte` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO Partes
    (`id_parte`, `nombre_parte`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Bocina'),
    (2, 'Jeringa'),
    (3, 'Mecánica')
;


CREATE TABLE Sub_Partes
    (`id_subparte` int, `nombre_subparte` varchar(70), `id_parte` int)
;

INSERT INTO Sub_Partes
    (`id_subparte`, `nombre_subparte`, `id_parte`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Bocina Der',1),
    (2, 'Bocina Central',1),
    (3, 'Jeringa Inf',2),
    (4, 'Jeringa Sup',2),
    (5, 'Motor Principal',3)
;
```

**b. Consulta**

```
SELECT 
  nombre_parte, GROUP_CONCAT(nombre_subparte SEPARATOR '|') as nombre_subparte
FROM 
  Partes p
LEFT JOIN 
  Sub_Partes sp 
ON p.id_parte=sp.id_parte
GROUP BY p.id_parte
;
```

**c. Resultado**

```
| nombre_parte |           nombre_subparte |
|--------------|---------------------------|
|       Bocina | Bocina Central|Bocina Der |
|      Jeringa |   Jeringa Inf|Jeringa Sup |
|     Mecánica |           Motor Principal |
```

Como puedes ver, en el resultado tienes exactamente lo que necesitas, en este caso, sin datos redundantes.

Aquí tienes el fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee561d/12

**d. Pero... ¿cómo presento eso en pantalla?**

Eso es lo de menos, por ejemplo, puedes a partir del resultado crear un array JSON  en el que la clave sea la columna 1 y el valor la columna 2 y a través de tu javascript separar los valores de la columna 2 usando el carácter |

**Nota final**
Las tablas de arriba las pensé, tratando de aproximarme a lo que quieres obtener. Si es exactamente esto, te sobra una tabla auxiliar para unir tus partes y subpartes (por eso hay sólo dos tablas). Ahora bien, si una subparte puede pertenecer a más de un grupo de partes (por ejemplo, que una "Bocina derecha" pueda pertenecer a la parte principal "Bocina" y al mismo tiempo a la parte principal "Jeringa"), entonces sí necesitarías una tercera tabla auxiliar.

Saludos.

Comment: no sabia del "GROUP_CONCAT" cual es lo equivalente en "Postgresql"? Podrias modificar el ej, por favor.

Comment: lo equivalente es: "array_agg()" mil gracias, me soluciono el problema.

Comment: En Postresql sería con string_agg: Ejemplo:  SELECT nombre_parte, string_agg(nombre_subparte,'|') as nombre_subparte ... y el resto de la consulta

Comment: con "array_agg()" creo un array y cuando lo retorno a la vista con un simple siclo lo divido a las diferentes subniveles.. gracias por las sugerencias presentadas en la respuestas. Mil gracias hermano.

Comment: De acuerdo. Me alegra que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Respecto al backend, dependiendo del serializador de laravel (que no lo conozco) la salida de `->toArray()` puede estar anidada, o bien tener la estructura de un array asociativo:

```
[
  0 => objeto,
  1 => objeto
  2 => objeto
]
```

lo cual conlleva que tus resultados se vayan anidando.

En el frontend, podrías probar el método [_.flattenDeep de la librería lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flattenDeep), para que no reinventes la rueda con un método recursivo sui generis.