# Como se realiza una funcion flecha?

Tags: javascript

```js
(() => {
  alert("Anonima auto ejecutable");
         
})();

var cualquiera = (() => alert("Tipo expresion"))();
```

Como puedo hacerla como una función normal?

Osea `function(){}`

ya que:

```js
cualquierFuncion() => alert("Error");
```

***No funciona***

Comment: La pregunta no incluye información sobre lo buscado/investigado. Falta de una descripción de lo que se quiere lograr.

Answer (score 2):

En tu primer ejemplo, estás encerrando la función de flecha dentro de una función anónima y ejecutándola pasándole los parámetros, en tu ejemplo no hace falta pasarle parámetros ya que no los necesita, por lo tanto la llamas **(tuFuncion)(tusParametros)**.

Tu segundo ejemplo, no es ejecutable debido a que no está bien formado.
Si quieres guardar la función anónima en una variable para posteriormente ejecutarla sería lo siguiente:

```
var someFunction = () => alert("Error");
someFunction();
```

O bien también podrías hacerlo en línea como tu primer ejemplo:

```
(() => alert("Error"))()
```

Para convertir una *función de flecha* a una *función normal* únicamente has de traducir la sintaxis:

```
var sumarNormalFunc = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

sumarNormalFunc(5, 5);

var sumarArrowFunc = (a, b) => { 
    return a + b
};

sumarArrowFunc(5, 5);
```

Fuente: [Enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Yo no estoy pidiendo una expresion funcional, sino una funcion tipo: function(){}, pero no anonima, sino con nombre

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir una funcion flecha a una funcion *normal*, seria de esta manera:

```js
var cualquiera = function() { alert("Tipo expression"); }
cualquiera();
```

Y la forma mas simple para hacer una funcion flecha seria:

```js
var cualquierFuncion = ()=> alert("Expression flecha");

cualquierFuncion()
```

Comment: No una expresion funcional

Comment: Puedes explicarte mejor? No tiendo lo que quieres decir.

Comment: Me diste una expresion funcional, yo pregunté por una funcion tipo function nombreFuncion(){}

Comment: Por tu comentario obviamente sabes como hacerla. Que exactamente es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: como realizar una funcion flecha usando el tipo function nombre(){} y NO una expresion funcional  var nombre = function(){};

Comment: No se puede. La sintaxis `function nombre() => {}` no es la especificada en el estandar. Lo mas parecido que puedes obtener es la que esta escrita en mi respuesta `var fn = ()=> { alert("fn body"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Está claro que si desea solo mostrar un `alert` estaría de más almacenar el resultado en una variable. Ya que no retornaría nada. *(solo para este ejemplo , en otros escenarios es posible que requiera asignar el valor de retorno)*

Entonces para convertir esta función a una normal y ejecutarla al mismo tiempo , se tendría que encerrar en paréntesis y al final hacer la llamada con `();`

```js
(function(){
  alert("Function cualquiera");
})();

/* Si no desea ejecutar al cargar , solo sería */
function funcionxy(){
  return alert("Function cualquiera");
}
/* Para luego hacer la llamada donde desee */

 /*funcionxy();*/
```

> No olvidar revisar una explicación más detallada sobre esto [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1799/cuando-usar-una-funci%C3%B3n-flecha-en-vez-de-una-funci%C3%B3n-com%C3%BAn?rq=1%C3%AD)

Comment: No respondes en nada a mi pregunta, pregunto lo equivalente a una funcion tipo funcion nombrefuncion(){}

Comment: Perdón no he comprendido bien su pregunta entonces _ninguna de las tres respuestas al parecer_ A qué se refiere? Más que convertir su función flecha a los dos casos planteados en mi respuesta no creo que exista otra forma. Saludos y disculpas la demora  en mi respuesta. Después de mucho recibo un - 1 en fin.